# Piping list of files and directories to du only shows sizes of directories?

Tags: pipe, disk-usage, xargs

Let's say I have a directory with multiple subdirectories, each of which contains some files:

```
1/a.txt
1/b.txt
2/c.txt
2/d.txt
3/e.txt
3/f.txt
```

I want to see the size of each file. Please keep in mind, I know there are easier and more direct ways to do this, such as `du -a`. I just want to know why the following doesn't work, for educational purposes.

---

### My pointless exercise

Running `find .` returns a list of all files and directories, so I tried piping it like so:

```
find . | xargs du
```

but that just returns the sizes of the directories 1, 2, and 3. I'm missing some bit of understanding, because in my mind `xargs` should be mapping each line of output from `find` to a call to `du`.

If instead I use:

```
find . | xargs du -a
```

then it works as expected, listing the sizes of all files and directories. It also works fine if I only pass it a list of files by using the `-type f` option, so it's something to do with receiving a list of directories mixed with files.

What's going on here?

Comment: you can also use `find -exec du {} \;` instead of piping to `xargs`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What's going on is that `xargs` puts (if it can) all of the names on one command-line, so that you see only one command passed to `du`.  Then `du` ignores the filenames (as you might expect: the files are part of the directories and it does not count those twice).

If you use a `-n 1` parameter to `xargs`, it will split the command up and you will see something more as you expect.

`find . | xargs -n 1 du -a`

Comment: Oh look at that. I never actually looked at the output of xargs (I just started boning up on unix tools a couple weeks ago). So am I right in thinking the main use of xargs is for when you're piping in a very big list, or when the following command can't read from stdin?

Comment: yes - and one use for the `-n` option is when you want only the ability to read `stdin`

Answer (score 0):

we can use below command

```
  find path -type f -printf "%s %p\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `-exec` function in `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec du -h {} \;
```